# VSTO Document level Customization

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, vsto, ms-office

I have developed a document-level Word 2010 customization. When prompt to open the document from my system or any other trusted location, it opens up just fine. But when I try to open the same document from the link in website, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException:
This document contains custom code that cannot be loaded because the location is
not in your trusted locations list: TestDocument.docx. If you trust this document
you can save and open it from a location on your computer.
```

I have signed the manifest using valid .pfx and certificate.

I have read some similar thread but found that customizations would run if the document is saved to the file system. You cannot make an Temp folder a trusted location. A certificate will not do it, it must be saved to a trusted location in the file system.

there is no problem when using macro for customization. Is it possible in VSTO customizations ??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the URL of the website to your Local Intranet/Trusted Sites in IE under Internet options.